# Writing Clob to File on local machine

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I am using a routine to populate clob data.
Now I need to write this data to a file(.html) on my local machine via an anonymous pl/sql block.

- The clob data contains data having html tags.

The code looks like 
    SET HEADING OFF 
    SET LINESIZE 32767 
    SET LONG 32767 
    SET PAGESIZE 0
    spool abc.html
    DECLARE
       v1 CLOB; 
       l_offset    INTEGER := 1;
    BEGIN
       proc1( v1); -- OUT parameter
     -- To spool data i am using dbms_output
       loop exit when l_offset > dbms_lob.getlength(l_clob);
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (dbms_lob.substr( l_clob, 255, l_offset));
         l_offset := l_offset + 255;
       end loop;
    END;

```
spool off
```

Doing this am able to get the content of clob in the file but the html file generated is not behaving in the expected manner( as writing 255 bytes at a time using dbms_output distorts html content ).

Is their any other way to write content of clob to a file on local machine?

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

> When you call PUT_LINE the item you specify is automatically followed
>   by an end-of-line marker. If you make calls to PUT to build a line,
>   then you must add your own end-of-line marker by calling NEW_LINE.
>   GET_LINE and GET_LINES do not return lines that have not been
>   terminated with a newline character.

Use [DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(item IN VARCHAR2) procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_output.htm#BABGHBIA)